# Collect async calls and submit the last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I try to create an image depend on an input field. The image created on the server, I get it by an async call, and it have to be generated after every keyup in the input field. If the user hit another key while the previous call isn't finished, this call have to be stucked. After the first call is finished, this stacked have to be called. The point, if the user hit a tons of keys while the first call is not finished, only the last one have to be called once.

[I created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kreestian/27gmpjj2/) for it, where I simulated the async call with a settimeout function. I can't figure out, why it isn't working.

```
var isRequestInProgress = false;
var nextRequest = null;

var submit = function(content) {
    console.log('isRequestInProgress: ' + isRequestInProgress);  // It should be true in the second turn
    if (isRequestInProgress === true) {
        nextRequest = content;
        return false;
    }
    isRequestInProgress = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        isRequestInProgress = true;
        if (nextRequest !== null) {
            submit(nextRequest);
        }

        nextRequest = null;
        isRequestInProgress = false;
    }, 2000);
};

$('button').click(function() {
    isRequestInProgress = false;
    submit($(this).text());
});
```

The `isRequestInProgress` should be true, if I press a button after another, in 2 mins. But it false, and I don't know, why...

if you know why, or you have a better solution to solve this problem, I would glad to hear it! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `isRequestInProgress` is always false because you make it `true` only after you call `console.log('isRequestInProgress: ' + isRequestInProgress);`

Comment: But in the second call, it will have the `true` value, while the first call is in progress.

Comment: Do you want to cancel all unfinished requests and make only the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using setTimeout, clear the timer using `clearTimeout` before submitting

http://jsfiddle.net/27gmpjj2/1/

If you're using Ajax, use `abort()`, as suggested by seva.rubbo

http://jsfiddle.net/27gmpjj2/2/

If you want to submit an ajax request only on the last button-press, then you can use the `setTimeout` approach. This will delay the request until we're sure the user has stopped pressing buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/27gmpjj2/5/

Comment: Ok, but the `setTimeout` only for simulate the ajax call. But the ajax don't have a `clearAjax`command.

Comment: @kree, It does. There is an `.abort()` method for `xhr` object in jQuery, for example. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ok, but it isn't the solution, what I looking for. I don't want to start the call.

Comment: You don't want to start the call. ajax requests will be sent immediately unless you wrap them in a setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right:

```
var isRequestInProgress = false,
    timeout;

var submit = function(content) {

    if (isRequestInProgress === true) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    isRequestInProgress = true;

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('content: ' + content); 
        isRequestInProgress = false;
    }, 2000);
};

$('button').click(function() {
    submit($(this).text());
});
```

Use `.abort()` method of `XMLHttpRequest` object to stop an AJAX request.